# String null value check concatenate string

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using below code to check string null or blank value and then concatenating field but this is not working - Can you please help..

```
 string result = abc__c.field1__c!=NULL ? abc__c.field1__c:''+  abc__c.field2__c != NULL ? abc__c.field2__c : '' +abc__c.field3__c != NULL ? abc__c.field3__c : '';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parentheses to make sure that the logic is parsed correctly:

```
string result = (abc__c.field1__c != NULL ? abc__c.field1__c : '')+
                (abc__c.field2__c != NULL ? abc__c.field2__c : '')+
                (abc__c.field3__c != NULL ? abc__c.field3__c : '');
```

The reason why is that the ternary operator is [right associative](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm), and + has a higher [precedence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm) than assignments (including ternary operators), so the default operation without parentheses looks like this:

```
string result = abc__c.field1__c != NULL ? abc__c.field1__c : (''+
                abc__c.field2__c != NULL ? abc__c.field2__c : (''+
                (abc__c.field3__c != NULL ? abc__c.field3__c : '')));
```

Which is not the intended effect.

Comment: Using parentheses around ternaries improves readability IMO even when it's not technically necessary.